# How to use trim function when declearing primary key in db2

Tags: db2

I would like to know how to use trim function when declaring primary key in db2.

For example, in table `Employee(name,id)` how to restrict the usage of these two insert statements:

```
insert into Employee(name,id) values (jay,1);
insert into Employee(name,id) values (jay,1);
```

In the above statements both `name` and `id` are primary keys.

Comment: no idea what the question is here.

Comment: I agree with @Hogan. What you are trying to do and why? What have you tried so far? Please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean unique? if so, well you can easily solve this problem, all you have to do, is to create a primary key on bouth fields ;-)

something like this:

`alter table Employee add constraint Employee_pk primary key (name, id)`

Comment: In the above two queries I want 'jay' and '  jay' to be treated the same. Currently the db treats them as different values. How do I make use of trim here to remove the white space in the latter case.

Comment: well this is something you can not do in the database using uniqueness.

Comment: this must be done when inserting the data. you have to "fix/trim" this on the input side / in the application.